# Is it possible to get a system microphone control icon next to the system volume control icon in the Gnome top bar

Tags: 18.04, sound, microphone

Is there a way to natively add a system microphone control icon next to the system volume control icon in the Gnome top bar?

Also, why is this control not there by default as system volume is?

Comment: I can only wonder why so many features that were present in the old GNOME have been removed. I use GNOME Flashback (the "old style" GNOME desktop, with the old panel & menus etc.) and the microphone control just is there, along with the output control.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the extension [Sound Input & Output Device Chooser](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/) which will modify the icon in the top bar, allowing you to change the input levels of the microphone, and to choose what device is active.

Comment: Many thanks Charles. I'm looking for a default configuration rather than an extension though... call me paranoid, or security conscious.

Comment: @Broadsworde I bet you don't like snaps much either!

Comment: Having been told they are less trusted, on this forum, correct!

Answer (score 0):

It's another extension, but I can definitely recommend [Nothing to Say](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1113/nothing-to-say/). Not only does it give very visual feedback on whether your microphone is active, it also gives you a global shortcut key to mute/unmute yourself.